# Matlab/Python Data Conversion

Tags: python, matlab

I am looking for a way to extract my data from huge text file and insert into excel-like format, e.g.;

```
blablablablabla
Loc1:38 
Loc1:77
blablablablablabla 
Loc2:-335 
.
.
.
```

I want those numbers and variables `Loc1`, `Loc2`, `38`, `335`, ... etc., in table format of excel, e.g.:

```
A1=Loc1 B1=38 C1=77
A2=Loc2 B2=-335
.
.
.
```

Then of course I will use the values in a matrix in Matlab, to sort according to my desired conditions and a nice graphic output, but this data conversion takes my time, does any one know how to target specific characters and export their subsequent char./data into excel table like this?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to not use python nor matlab. Use grep and awk

```
grep Loc1 filename | awk -F":" '{print $2}' > Loc1.txt
grep Loc2 filename | awk -F":" '{print $2}' > Loc2.txt
```

and then simply read Loc1.txt and Loc2.txt into a table using your favorite tool (use matlab or python)

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure if this is what you want but you could use notepad search and replace funktion and just do 
find :

replace with =